# Word choice for notice

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, vocabulary

What other verbs are proper to substitute for "notice" in the following sentence so as to mean the same or similarly?

"Did you notice what intonation pattern of the example sentence was?"

1. hear
2. find
3. find out
4. realize
5. catch
6. discover
7. observe
8. perceive
9. note

Comment: Hear, catch, perceive, note. "Catch" is a little casual, "perceive" is slightly technical.

Comment: Please tell us what you have worked out so far with [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) and [searching for those words in context](https://duckduckgo.com). This isn't a dictionary service.

Comment: @gotube Those words I listed are the results that I googled and looked up in the dictionaries. But, I am not sure which ones are proper to use in the sentence I made since the dictionaries don't have explicit explanations in this regard. And I don't think anyone needs to and is obliged to answer my question. If someone would like to help at will, that would be very appreciated from me.

Answer (score 1):

Most of them have the a similar meaning to **"were you aware of the intonation pattern"** with the exception of **"find"** and **"discover"** which have would a more **"did you actively search for the intonation pattern"** sense in that phrase.